# Condition $\overline{V^{p,q}}= V^{q,p}$ in the definition of a Hodge structure

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, hodge-theory

Suppose that $V$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-module. A Hodge structure of wight $k$ on $V$ is a decomposition of the complexification of $V$ into complex vector spaces $V^{p,q}$ such that $\overline{V^{p,q}}=V^{q,p}$. More precisely:

$$
V\otimes_\mathbb Z \mathbb C = \bigoplus_{p+q=k} V^{p,q} .
$$

I'm struggling to see how it is possible that $\overline{V^{p,q}}=V^{q,p}$ without getting $V^{p,q}=V^{q,p}$.

My reasoning is the following: even if the $V^{p,q}$ are taken as external, abstract, vector spaces, hence having abstract complex-conujugations, then in the end they must be compatible with the canonical conjugation on $V\otimes \mathbb C$, which means (if I'm not wrong) that we can consider the $V^{p,q}$ directly as complex subspaces.

Now, in this case, I cannot imagine how $\overline{V^{p,q}}$ could be different from $V^{p,q}$ itself, for if $v\otimes z$ is an element in it, then
$$
\overline{v\otimes z}=v\otimes\bar z = \frac{\bar z}{z}(v\otimes z ),
$$
which means that both $v\otimes z$ and $\overline{v\otimes z}$ belong to the same (complex) vector space. Hence, as sets $V^{p,q}=\overline{V^{p,q}}$.

I'm aware of the related question [Definition of complex conjugate in complex vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119801/definition-of-complex-conjugate-in-complex-vector-space) and the ones mentioned on there, as well as the book Linear algebra and geometry by Kostrikin & Manin (1989) and the notes of Keith Conrad about complexification (availabe [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf)).

PS: In the case of manifolds, the complex-conjugation used carries $dz$ into $d\bar z$ and, if I'm not mistaken, and there are no possibility of relating both $dz$ and $d\bar z$ algebraically, but with the above complex-conjugation there is, so this example would not be valid.

Comment: Maybe an example will help? Consider $V = \mathbb C^2$ with the subspaces $V^{1,0} = \mathbb C \cdot (1, i)$ and $V^{0,1} = \mathbb C \cdot (1, -i)$. Each subspace is a line spanned by a vector $v$ and $w$, and $\overline w = v$, but $\overline{V^{1,0}} = V^{0,1} \not= V^{1,0}$.

Comment: @Dog_69: Elements of $V^{p,q}$ are in general **linear combinations** of elements of the form $v \otimes z$ (you only know that $V^{p,q}$ is a subspace of $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$) and then your argument doesn't work.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Of course it helps!! I tried to come up with one but I couldn't. It seems I didn't try hard enough, thanks!

Comment: @levap Is it only that? Of course my argument doesn't work for a linear combination, but I hadn't realised that points one of my mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: @Dog_69: Let's say $W$ is a complex subspace of $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$. Your argument shows that if $v \otimes z \in W$ then also $\overline{v \otimes z} \in W$. However, it might be the case that $W$ doesn't have any (non-zero) elements of the form $v \otimes z$. For example, if we identify $\mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$ and consider the subspace $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{C}} \{ (1,i) \}$ then this subspace is precisely the $\mathbb{C}$-span of $e_1 \otimes 1 + e_2 \otimes i$ and it is not closed under conjugation.

Comment: @levap your previous comment made completely clear I was wrong, but thanks for adding more details.