# A restricted complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, multilinear-algebra

Assume that $x$ is an n-dimensional vector of complex values, namely $x= x_{re} + ix_{im}$ where both $x_{re}$ and $x_{im}$ are n-dimensional real column vectors.

Assume that we restrict $x_{im}$ to be always the same vector, while $x_{re}$ can be any real vector.

What are the properties of corresponding restricted complex vector space? Does such a restricted complex vector space have significance? Is there a mathematical notion describing such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'll notate with tuples for the simplicity, but we're still talking about the same thing. At any rate, you'd have something like $\{(x_1+ai, ..., x_n+ai): a,x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb{R})\}$. We'll call this $A$.

The most notable property of this is that it is, in fact, not a vector space. Recall our requirements ([here](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Ebeachy/courses/240/06spring/vectorspace.html) is a nicely done list that was at the top of my Google results).

If we ever have $a$ (that is, $x_{im}$) non-zero, we run into some issues. I'll leave this to you, but will tag on that it's the same reason as to why the empty set isn't a vector space (at least, that's probably the lowest-hanging fruit; it breaks more than just one of our criteria).

> If $a\neq 0$, then $0\notin A$.

> If $a\neq 0$, it is not closed under addition nor scalar multiplication. Consider $u+v$ for $u,v \in A$. Any one coordinate would have complex part $a$, but $u+v$ would have complex part $2a$, thereby meaning that $u+v\notin A$. Scalar multiplication is similar.

> I'll drop an et cetera here. Your defined set of vectors does not only break those three axioms alone.

As to a mathematical notion for this: we'd need $a=0$ for this to be a vector space, but, at that point, we'd just have $\mathbb{R}^n$ with some extra steps. The remaining pieces of your questions were rather directly tied to this being a vector space; delving into such discussion in the terms of vector spaces isn't really bringing us much, though the notion is interesting! That being said, [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5233/vivid-examples-of-vector-spaces) may be of interest as well. [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897662/restriction-of-scalars-from-bbb-c-to-bbb-r-for-vector-spaces) is probably of value to link as well. Thirdly, you may find abstract algebra interesting if you like exploring questions like these; the field deals with such structures.

Edit: a second thought that might be somewhat more insightful.

Consider constructing this proposed set of vectors as the span of a vector or two. What would those vectors be here? Definitely tough to put together (and really, you can't). Fix $n$. Pick a set of $n$ basis vectors to span our proposed vector space. ...

Where does this fall apart?

Comment: Yes you are right that this is not a vector space. However, we can still change or tweak addition and multiplication operations, can't we? Perhaps it still will not be a vector space, but at least we may sustain closure somehow. Your last thought sounds promising also.

Comment: If we were to tweak our definitions of multiplication and addition, it would leave us still without a vector space; think about adding two complex numbers and where that puts us geometrically. I'm assuming you're meaning to leave out the complex part or something like that: $ca+cbi$ sends us to a place very different from $ca+bi$. 

The last thought was to put a more geometric intuition behind this. Every vector space can be written as the span of vectors, and every span of vectors is a vector space.